# Realtime Streaming of SQL SERVER (RDS) transactions to NoSQL

Tags: sql-server, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a situation where I want to stream all the Updates, Deletes and Inserts from my AWS RDS SQL Server to a NoSQL DB such as DynamoDB or RethinkDB.

What I am trying to achieve is to divide my users into critical and non critical databases reducing the load on my rds server and using technologies like rethinkdb or dynamodb streams to send the other set of data (non critical) to front end.

I have thought of various ways to do this:

1. the most obvious to just asynchronously make entry in both databases though I can end up in a situation where one of the entries may fail.
2. two is to use RabbitMQ or queing service aws sqs to que the second entry and make sure that it inserts.
3. (which I want to achive) is if somehow a nodejs service can listen to mssql streams and push the content to nosql.

What can be done in a situation like this?

The profit I am looking for is to store a dataset in nosql that can be served to over 100k users as they all want to see the same data with just some where clause changes and in realtime. This in turn will reduce the RDS Server transactions to a minimum reads and writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 approach below :

1. [AWS DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/near-zero-downtime-migration-from-mysql-to-dynamodb/)
2. Or, [combining EMR, Amazon Kinesis, and Lambda (with custom scripts)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/near-zero-downtime-migration-from-mysql-to-dynamodb/)

Comment: I am in talks of making this work (with aws support) cause the tutorial (option 2) is for mysql and nothing is available to mssql, but yeah this is the right way